# Stay login and set cookie with request module in python and do stuff

Tags: python, cookies, authentication, python-requests

I logged in to my account like:

```
import os
import requests
from lxml import html

def GetContent(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.content

def Parser(content):
    tree = html.fromstring(content)
    return [e.text_content() for e in tree.xpath('//div[@class="group"]/div[@class="groupinfo"]/a')]


def Func():
    try:
        s = requests.Session()
        email='user'
        password='123456'
        post_data={'email':email, 'password':password}
        post_response=s.post(url='http://site.ir/signin/', data=post_data)
        resultfile = open("result.txt", "w+")
        page=1
        while (page<=750):
            print
            print 'Checking page number: ', page
            url2 = 'http://site.ir/' + str(page)
            print "URL: " + url2
            content = GetContent(url2)
            results = Parser(content)
            for i in results:
                print i
                resultfile.writelines(i+'\n')
                resultfile.flush()
            page += 1
        resultfile.close()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print "\nKeyboardInterruption with Ctrl+c signal"
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Func()
```

I want to stay loggin and do stuff. I made a session as you see in code.

when the page is increasing I want to stay login and get content the next page and do stuff,,, but it returns me only **content** of page number 1 while page is increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are ignoring your session in `GetContent`; you are making a request without the cookies that your `requests.Session` object tracks.

Just remove the function altogether and use `s.get()` instead.

```
print "URL: " + url2
content = s.get(url2).content
results = Parser(content)
```

Comment: Thank you... The error `TypeError: expected string or buffer` appears

Comment: The output of `print content` is `<Response [200]>`

Comment: @MortezaLSC: adjusted, you want the `.content` attribute of the response.